# VBA Create Path with variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in VBA so i came here to get some help. So I have a sheet with a lot of names and when I press a name I want it to go to a directory that I have all the information about it and open the txt file that have the same name as the cell. (The directory as the same name as the cell but the txt file as a S befora the name).

This is what i got so far:

```
Sub Import_TxtFile()

Debug.Print ActiveCell
variavel = ActiveCell
Debug.Print variavel
Dim X As Double
Dim TXT As String

Open "\\10.0.9.210\Public\"&variavel&"\S"&variavel& For Input As #1

X = 0

    Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, TXT
    Cells(2, 2).Offset(X, 0) = TXT
    X = X + 1
    Loop

Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue with the code that you have?

Comment: When I press the cell nothing happens.

Comment: Why should something happen when you press a cell? The sub you gave is not an event handler. How are you running the code?

Comment: The code isn't running because is incomplete. But I think i'm doing something wrong in the path aswell because it is red. I want to select a cell by double clicking on it so the txt file appear on page but i don't know how that's why I'm reaching for help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'open' the text file? Are you trying to Read or Write the file? Your code is mixing the 2 concepts.

Comment: Regarding the path you need spaces between the ampersands. And don't need the last ampersand.

Comment: I want the information on the txt file to go to excel worksheet.

Comment: Like this? 
Open "\\10.0.9.210\Public\"& variavel &"\S"variavel For Input As #1

Comment: `Open "\\10.0.9.210\Public\" & variavel & "\S" & variavel For Input As #1`

Comment: Still stuck in here. How can i make it read the cell?